# Inconsistent OpenAL popping artifact when switching volume of sounds in iOS (certain versions)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, openal

When playing a lower volume sound (.05f) after a playing a normal (1.0f) volume sound in OpenAL, I'm getting a popping noise. It happens only in the following iOS/devices:
iPad 3.2, iPhone 4.1, iPad 4.2, iPhone 4.2.

No popping noise on iPhone 4.0, iPhone 4.3, and iPad 4.3. Any possible ideas of what could be going on? My OpenAL sound engine is based on this site:
http://www.gehacktes.net/2009/03/iphone-programming-part-6-multiple-sounds-with-openal/

Answer (score 0):

Had solved this issue a couple months ago. The reason why this strange popping sounds occur - i guess iOS emulates openAL sources badly. Try to recreate new openAL sound source for every new sound playback, this helps me.

Good luck!